# Is there anyway to get "Effective Spring Config" from all spring beans annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

I liked annotations used for bean declaration etc. But now we have so many beans with order (@Depends). It is tough to maintain or look at a glance the configuration.

Is there any tool that provides "Effective Spring Config" information based on all your bean annotations?

Comment: I would suggest you reword this to be a fit question. FE, "How can I get the "Effective Spring Config"  information based on all my bean annotations?" It's probably a pretty useful post when not asking for a tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: you should not be using that many `@DependsOn` annotations.

From the javadoc:

> Used infrequently in cases where a bean
>   does not explicitly depend on another through properties or
>   constructor arguments, but rather depends on the side effects of
>   another bean's initialization.

You can just do this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   public MovieClient movieClient(RestOperations rest) {
       return new MovieClientImpl(rest);
   }

   @Bean
   public RestOperations restOps() {
       return new RestTemplate();
   }

}
```

In this example, the `RestOperations` bean will be instantiaded **before** the `MovieClient` bean, just because the movieClient bean **asks for it in the constructor**. You don't need any `@DependsOn` annotion in cases like this one.

---

**Edit**: as OP commented, there is still the issue of showing the "Effective Spring Config".

I do not think there is any tool for that, because your dependencies may change at runtime (because of AutoConfiguration, `@Conditional` annotations, profiles, other?).

If you need to know your "Effective Spring Config" (i.e. "what beans are present at runtime"), you can do this:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContest context;
context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, finalArgs);
// Print all the beans:
System.out.println(context.getBeanDefinitionNames());
```

However, if you meant **how can you view and navigate all the configuration**, you can organize your beans in different `@Configuration` files, pick them up using `@ComponentScan`, and navigate them using the Spring IDE pluguin for Eclipse, like this:

[image: Navigate Spring Configuration]

Comment: It still has issue of knowing all dependencies as on single truth document :)

Comment: @gpa don't put all your `beans` on a single `Configuration` file. You should split them by some criteria into different files, such as `MongoConfiguration` class, `MvcConfiguration` class, etc. Then, a single `ComponentScan` annotation will load all of them (and even solve inter-depencies). Simple as that ;)

Comment: @gpa I have updated my answer to address the issue of knowing all dependencies.